How to mix speaker and microphone audio signal in cpp without noise
I am working on developing a screen recorder application using c++ in windows. In the application when I enable only output audio (i.e. speakers), the speaker audio is recorded smoothly without noise. Similarly when I enable only input audio (i.e. microphone), the microphone audio is also recorded smoothly without noise. But when I enable both input and output audio and try to mix those two audio signals, the mixed audio became distorted.
I have stored the input (microphone) audio and output (speaker) audio into 2 separated vectors named std::vector &inputAudio and std::vector &outputAudio.
Here is the code of generating the audioBuffer.
std::vector<BYTE> MediaRecorder::MixInputOutputAudio(std::unique_ptr<AudioRecorder>& pInputDevice, std::unique_ptr<AudioRecorder>& pOutputDevice)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> audioBuffer;

    if (mIsOutputDeviceEnabled && mIsInputDeviceEnabled)
    {
        // both input, output devices enabled 
        // mix buffers from output device and input device since VideoSinkWriter works only with one Audio sink
        audioBuffer = Utilities::MixAudio(pOutputDevice->GetRecordedBytes(), pInputDevice->GetRecordedBytes());
    }
    else if (mIsOutputDeviceEnabled)
    {
        // set the audio buffer by taking bytes from output audio device
        audioBuffer = pOutputDevice->GetRecordedBytes();
    }
    else if (mIsInputDeviceEnabled)
    {
        // set the audio buffer by taking bytes from input audio device
        audioBuffer = pInputDevice->GetRecordedBytes();
    }

    return audioBuffer;
}

Here is the function "MixAudio" in which I tried to Mix input and output audio. parameter "first" is the output audio and parameter "second" is the input audio.
static std::vector<BYTE> MixAudio(std::vector<BYTE> &first, std::vector<BYTE> &second)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> newvector;

    if (first.size() >= second.size())
    {
        // This will overlay both the samples
        newvector.insert(newvector.end(), first.begin(), first.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < second.size(); i++)
        {
            newvector[i] += second[i];
    }
    }
    else
    {
        //This will clip the second sample to the length of the first.
        vector<BYTE>::iterator end = first.size() > 0 ? second.begin() += first.size() : second.end();
        newvector.insert(newvector.end(), second.begin(), end);

        for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++)
        {
            newvector[i] += first[i];
    }
    }

    return newvector;
}

Here "BYTE" means unsigned char. The problem is in this "MixAudio" function when I tried to mix two audio, the mix audio is distorted and generating noise.
What am I doing wrong? Can anyone please suggest a solution?

The structure of sound files is typically vectors of 16 bit signed ints or floats. You can't just add the bytes (chars). You have to add each sound sample as well as scale things to prevent overflow.

My recoreded sounds are vector of bytes. I added each sound samples individually and tried to average the added sample.Even I tried to clip the added sample to 255.But the result was same

newvector[i] += second[i]; I am sure you will get overflows (values too big to fit in BYTE). First add them to a vector of 16 bit variables. Then normalize back to 8 bits.

How can I normalize to 8 bits. Basic average do not work ??

Here's an example. Take two audio streams consisting of single samples, 1 and -1. These are the minimum non zero amplitudes and when combined should yield 0. But if we add the bytes we get this: 0x01, 0x00 (= 1), 0xff, 0xff (= -1) : Sum of bytes= 0x00, 0xff which is -256. That's why you get noise.

How exactly are you capturing the recordings?  That is, what API are you using, and with what configuration settings?  That information is necessary to know how to properly mix them.
